# access to cell MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
for m=1:numel(myFolder)

end


for x = 1:numel(myFiles)  %
    for j=1:numel(myFolder)            
        eachFile{x}{j} = dir(myFiles{x}{j});            
    end
end
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
for x = 1:numel(myFiles)
      for y = 1:numel(myFiles{x})
          eachFile{x}{j} = dir(myFiles{x}{y}); 
      end
end
```